Why unable to flash the code when MCU(stm32u575) is in Stop2 Low power mode?
This is the method I am using below method to put on sleep mode which is working and wakeup also working based on configuration, but when I try to flash using jlink in when MCU is in sleep mode it is failing.
Thanks in advance!

    osDelay(100);
    // Internal Peripheral De-initialized
    HAL_UART_DeInit(&huart1);
    HAL_I2C_DeInit(&hi2c1);
    HAL_I2C_DeInit(&hi2c4);
    HAL_TIM_PWM_DeInit(&htim3);
    HAL_TIM_Base_DeInit(&htim4);
    HAL_TIM_Base_DeInit(&htim15);
//    HAL_TIM_PWM_DeInit(&htim2);   // TODO: @sagar test

    /* Enable the LPUART clock in Autonomous Mode */
    __HAL_RCC_LPUART1_CLKAM_ENABLE();

    /* Enable the LPUART in Stop Mode */
    HAL_UARTEx_EnableStopMode(&hlpuart1);

    /*Suspend Tick increment to prevent wakeup by Systick interrupt.
    Otherwise the Systick interrupt will wake up the device within 1ms (HAL time base)*/
    HAL_SuspendTick();
    SysTick->CTRL &= ~SysTick_CTRL_TICKINT_Msk;

    /* Enter STOP2 Mode, wake up is done once any interrupt detected on UART2 or CHG or Buttons */
    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
    LL_PWR_SetPowerMode(LL_PWR_STOP2_MODE);
    HAL_PWREx_EnterSTOP2Mode(PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);

    /* Resume Tick interrupt if disabled prior to SLEEP mode entry */
    SysTick->CTRL  |= SysTick_CTRL_TICKINT_Msk;
    HAL_ResumeTick();

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    // Internal Peripheral Initialized
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    MX_I2C1_Init();
    MX_I2C4_Init();
    MX_TIM3_Init();
    MX_TIM4_Init();
    MX_TIM15_Init();
//    MX_TIM2_Init(); // TODO: @sagar test

    /* Wake Up based on RXNE flag successful */
    HAL_UARTEx_DisableStopMode(&hlpuart1);


tried disabling stop2 power mode

Hi @hetal, Did you find the answer? In my case, I can't program the device until I perform a power cycle.

No, not yet got any proper solution

One of my colleague has shared below reference from STM32 community posts that might work:


https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-products/which-reset-pin-to-use-stm32f407vgt-vs-stm32f4-discovery/td-p/521695


https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-boards-and-hardware/njtrst-different-from-nrst-on-stm32l412/td-p/69859


https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0456-stm32u5-series-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf


